# ToolStripLabel does not redraw instantanously

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have an application which opens an image and displays it in the window. To be exact I store this image in inner field of the form class and draw it in the method attached to `Paint` event of a `Panel` placed on that form. It's like this:

```
private void pnlImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    if (image != null)
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, imageLocation);
    }
}
```

The variable `image` is a field of the form class (of type `Image`) containing the image after opening; `imageLocation` is connected to scrolling and scrollbars, which is irrelevant to this case.

On that form I also placed a `ToolStrip` on the bottom of it, and on this `ToolStrip` there are some `ToolStripLabels`, which are supposed to be some indicators about the image. E.g. there is a `ToolStripLabel`, which I want to show current position of mouse cursor over my image, or - from the other point of view - pixel position (on the image) under the mouse cursor. So I update value of my label(s) in the method attached to the `MouseMove` event, like this:

```
private void pnlImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCursorAtLabel(e.X, e.Y); // <---- method of interest
    UpdateColorLabel(e.X, e.Y); // other label, showing color of the pixel. It's an identical thing, so I did not mention it
}
```

And the contents of method `UpdateCursorAtLabel(int, int)`, directly responsible for updating the "cursor at" label is:

```
void UpdateCursorAtLabel(int cursorX, int cursorY)
{
    lblCursorAtValue.Text = image != null ? 
        String.Format("{0}, {1}", scbHorizontal.Value + cursorX, scbVertical.Value + cursorY) :
        nullText;
    lblCursorAtValue.Invalidate();
}
```

`lblCursorAtValue` - this is the label which should show position of pixel under mouse, e.g. "234, 117".
`scbHorizontal`, `scbVertical` - just some scrollbars, irrelevant, I just need them to calculate position.
`nullText` - `const string`, equals "---".

And at the beginning there was no using of `Invalidate()` method. When I made this all, I noticed, that as I move cursor over my panel, contents of the label does not change at all! Only when I **stop** moving cursor, I can see the new value of label. So I added `lblCursorAtValue.Invalidate()` to enforce redrawing of label. Still the same problem. I even checked one more thing - attached a method to the `Paint` event of this label, not filling it, and put there a breakpoint. In runtime debugger stopped there only after I stopped moving cursor, or got it out of bounds of the Panel. There are no such methods on the `ToolStripLabel` as `Update()` or `Refresh()`, so I can't use anything stronger than `Invalidate()`. I really don't get why this is happening, and how could I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I forgot one crucial thing. And the `UpdateColorLabel(int, int)` method isn't as irrelevant as it seemed at the beginning. Because it's like:

```
void UpdateColorLabel(int cursorX, int cursorY)
{
    if (image == null)
    {
        lblColorValue.Text = nullText;
    }
    else
    {
        var imageCursorLocation = new Point(scbHorizontal.Value + cursorX, scbVertical.Value + cursorY);
        var px = new Bitmap(image).GetPixel(imageCursorLocation.X, imageCursorLocation.Y);
        lblColorValue.Text = String.Format("R = {0}, G = {1}, B = {2}", px.R, px.G, px.B);
    }            
}
```

And inside it there is one line, which was messing up everything:

```
var px = new Bitmap(image).GetPixel(imageCursorLocation.X, imageCursorLocation.Y);
```

Yes, in this line I was creating **whole new bitmap**, after every **mouse move by one pixel!!!** Creating bitmap is rather time-consuming operation. So application did not have time to update look of my labels, because it was busy creating hundreds of bitmaps...

I fixed it by storing Bitmap, not Image, so I wouldn't have to create it just to get pixel color.